# Select in Aurelia using Materialize css

Tags: javascript, jquery, aurelia

I am trying to create a select dropdown using Materialize css
in my template file `order.html`. I have the following

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <select multiple>
          <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
          <option value="1">Option 1</option>
          <option value="2">Option 2</option>
          <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
      </div>
</div>
```

In order to make it work I am using making the following call using jquery

```
$('select').material_select();
```

I am also importing the following libraries:

```
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.2/css/materialize.min.css">
```

My question is how do i use the jquery `$('select').material_select();` in `order.js` so that I can make it work. 
Thanks

Comment: I've written a blog about integrating third party libraries into Aurelia here: http://davismj.me/blog/aurelia-drag-and-drop/

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid using jQuery in your view models. If you to manipulate the DOM (with or without jQuery), create [custom attribute](http://aurelia.io/docs#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.1.4/doc/article/cheat-sheet/8) or [custom element](http://aurelia.io/docs#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.1.4/doc/article/cheat-sheet/9).

There are already some Aurelia [plugins for Materialize CSS](https://github.com/aurelia-ui-toolkits/aurelia-materialize-bridge) that you can use. However, if you don't require some advanced options, you can just create your own simple attribute, like this:

```
import {customAttribute} from 'aurelia-templating';
import {inject} from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';
import $ from 'jquery';

@customAttribute('material-select')
@inject(Element)
export class MaterialSelect {
  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
  }

  attached() {
    $(this.element).material_select();
  }

  detached() {
    $(this.element).material_select('destroy');
  }
}
```

Code is taken from an older version of [Aurelia Materialize plugin](https://github.com/manuel-guilbault/aurelia-materialize/blob/master/src/select.js).